# Equality test failing for eval(repr(object)) in python3

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, eval, repr

Here's the `__repr__` method inside a class called `Grid`

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'Grid(%r, %r)' % (self.rows, self.cols)
```

and I've put some basic tests inside a `unittest` module to check if `eval` can do an equality test without failure, and that looks like this:

```
# One of the tests inside a unittest.TestCase subclass
def test_grid(self):
    grid = Grid(3, 4)
    self.assertEqual(eval(repr(grid)), grid)
```

Now, this is the test report (I've isolated this test from others):

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_grid (tests.test_core.TestCore)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Desktop/sample/tests/test_core.py", line 14, in test_grid
    self.assertEqual(eval(repr(grid)), grid)
AssertionError: Grid(3, 4) != Grid(3, 4)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.003s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

The Assertion exception message is even more confusing to me. Isn't `Grid(3, 4) != Grid(3, 4)` supposed to be `False`?

Comment: Have you implemented `Grid.__eq__`? Otherwise `g1 == g2` defaults to `g1 is g2`.

Comment: No, I have not. So, are they both made (repr and eq) for every classes that wishes to use eval to recreate the object?

Comment: No, you only need `__repr__` for `eval`, but you need `__eq__` to compare equality.

Comment: Also note that you don't *"recreate the object"* as such, you create *a new object* that has *the same attributes*, hence `g1 is not g2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the core of the issue is that you are creating a new object, and even though the values are the same inside - python cannot tell that they are, so it compares object by references. And they are different. I believe you need to override python's magic comparison operator to be able to compare by internal values.

Comment: I'm assuming that an `a is b` case would be `True` here, right (rather than `a == b`)? Does everyone implement both eq and repr for this eval-object-creation?

Comment: @RenaeLider I am a python beginner myself, so I will be able to answer these questions only after testing, but then, you could do that too. As for 'eq', I think you need to implement both.

Comment: @RenaeLider If b is eval(repr(a)), b is a copy of a and `b is not a`. Rusty's answer is correct.  So are Jon's comments. If one writes a __repr__ that can be eval-ed, one is not required to write __eq__ unless one wants `==` to work.

Comment: Thank you @TerryJanReedy. I am reading more about it now. I think `eq` is usually done for comparing container types or numbers or strings. So i might need to implement this along with the `repr`. Eventually I will be looking at something like `eval(repr(grid_1)) == grid_1` by comparing their internal containers (like a dict or a list).